# Can I re-ask a question here that I asked on physics.SE?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on the physics site that is basically me being stuck on showing something by integrating by parts and there is no physical reasoning involved, just the odd Quantum Mechanics word.

I didn't get a response over in Physics, but I'm pretty sure that someone here would be able to clear up my issue pretty quick, can I re-post the question here?

Comment: I would say: wait a week after asking.  If you don't get an answer by then, consider posting elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not getting a helpful response on physics.SE, ask the moderators there to migrate the question to math.SE.

If, as J.M. mentions, it is too old to migrate, then you can ask your question on math.SE, but should probably put a notice at the front of your old question that it has been moved to math.SE (including a link to the new question). Then anyone who wants to contribute can look on math.SE to make sure they are not duplicating efforts there.

Comment: ...but if it's "too old to migrate", then things are slightly hairier.

Comment: @J.M.: good point. I've made a suggestion for that.

Comment: @J.M.: Wax on, wax off... :-P

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware, provided a question is relevant in multiple SEs, it's fine to post it in two places provided that you explain that you have done so in each question. It's also good practice to provide a link from your old question to the new one (and vice versa) so that answerers can see what responses you have already, and prevent duplication of effort.